# Do I need the cache directories from old versions of IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: macos, disk-space, cache, intellij-idea

These folders are taking up a fair amount of disk space so I'd like to get rid of them if possible. I'm using version 2018.2 at the moment so I'll keep hold of that one.

These folders *shouldn't* have anything in that I need to keep but has anyone ever had experience of things going wrong when they deleted them?

[image: macos desktop showing size of each version of IDEA's cache directory]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need these directories and they can be safely deleted. In my case, these directories appear to have been cleaned up automatically for me for past versions as I only have the latest version's folders. I'm not sure whether this is from using [Toolbox](https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox/) to manage my JetBrains app installation and upgrade process, but either way the old folders can be safely deleted and they will be re-created if you happen to open an old version of the app.